# Drag and drop animation recoils back to source

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop

Drag and drop animation from a NSTableView to another window's NSTextView recoils back to source view rather than into textview. The drag-and-drop action works fine otherwise—my data gets pasted. My NSTextView's subclass has all the drag-and-drop protocol methods under the sun (see code below). What might be going wrong?

```
- (void)awakeFromNib { // Adjust default insets
[self setTextViewInset];
[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:AWNDragNDropGeneralRuleRecordType, nil]]; 
[self registerAsObserver];
}

- (void)registerAsObserver
{
    [self addObserver:scrollerSubclass
           forKeyPath:@"focused"
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:NULL];
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    NSLog(@"Accepting");
    [self setFocused:YES];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    NSLog(@"Resigning");
    [self setFocused:NO];
    [super resignFirstResponder]; // Otherwise cursor remains in textView
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    NSLog(@"Becoming");
    return YES;
}

- (void)setFocused:(BOOL)x
{
    NSLog(@"-setFocused: is called with %d",x);
    focused = x;
}


- (BOOL)focused
{
    NSLog(@"-focused: is returning %d",focused);
    return focused;
}


- (BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepareForDragOperation YES");
    return YES;
}


- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSLog(@"draggingEntered:");
    if ([sender draggingSource] == self) {
        return NSDragOperationNone;
    }

    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}


- (void)draggingExited:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Draging Exited:");
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}


- (void)draggingEnded:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    [self performDragOperation:sender];     
}

- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{ // Look for drag source in 'SpellRuleFiles.SpellRulesWindowDelegate tableView delegate method
    NSPasteboard *pb = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    if (![self readFromPasteboard:pb]) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Could not read from dragging pasteboard");
        NSLog(@"performDragOperation NO");
        return NO;
    }
    NSLog(@"performDragOperation YES");
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)readFromPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pb 
{ // Source of paste data is 'SpellRuleFile's ' 

    // I'm not showing this code

    return YES;     
}

- (void)concludeDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSLog(@"conclude drag operation:");
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In -prepareForDragOperation: you want to set sender.animatesToDestination = NO, in which case, the things that are getting dragged will just disappear when you drop them, instead of recoiling back.

Or, if you want something nicer but more complicated, you can use -enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:etc:etc: to go through each of the items that are getting dropped onto your text view and set their draggingFrame appropriately, in which case the things that are getting dragged will animate to a final destination of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, however the animation still recoils. My hunch is that by using a subclass of NSTextView somehow its window First Responder does not react to the dragging event. I'm not sure what to do about this possibility.